# downgrading a package in R

Tags: r, installation, package

I recently installed the `forecast` package, using `install.packages()`.
The latest version (6.1) has been successfully installed but I want to install the forecast package version 5.9. So I used :

`install.packages('http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/forecast/forecast_5.9.tar.gz', repos=NULL, type='source')`

But when using library I get an error:

```
install.packages('http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/forecast/forecast_5.9.tar.gz', repos=NULL, type='source')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/forecast/forecast_5.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 156982 bytes (153 KB)
downloaded 153 KB

* installing *source* package 'forecast' ...
** package 'forecast' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="forecast.dll" OBJECTS="calcBATS.o calcTBATS.o etsTargetFunction.o etsTargetFunctionWrapper.o etscalc.o etspolyroot.o makeBATSMatrices.o makeTBATSMatrices.o updateMatrices.o updateTBATSMatrices.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'forecast'
* removing 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.2/forecast'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.2/forecast'
Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\...\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\00LOCK-forecast\forecast\libs\x64\forecast.dll to C:\Users\...\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\forecast\libs\x64\forecast.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\...\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" "C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQzO3Zp/downloaded_packages/forecast_5.9.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQzO3Zp/downloaded_packages/forecast_5.9.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: what happens if you first remove `forecast`6.1 _before_ installing 5.9?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to install forecast version 5.9(Its not a problem if you have forecast 6.1 already installed,it would install 5.9 separately meaning that you would see two forecast packages in the installed packages ).
Go to the  link https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/forecast/ 
Download forecast 5.9(just click on it,it would start downloading the  file.
Now open the R studio,click on install packages and change install from to : Package archive File(and just browse it to the location of zip file).And your package would be installed.
While using the forecast package in my case it didnt work(the function that uses forecast package) when both the forecast package where loaded.So i use forecast 5.9 making sure that 6.1 isnt loaded.
Hope that helps